# Limits with inequality

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I try to prove a simple statement:

*Let $a,b\in R$, $a<b$, and $F:(a,b)\rightarrow R$. Given $F(x)<A$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, we have $lim_{x\rightarrow c} F(x)\leq A$ for $c=a,b$ (assuming limits exist at endpoints).*

Here is my proof:

Let $c=a$. Suppose $lim_{x\rightarrow a} F(x)> A$. Choose $\epsilon= lim_{x\rightarrow a} F(x)-A$. Then, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ in the punctured neighborhood $N_{\delta}^* (a)\cap (a,b)$, we have $F(x)>A$, contradicting the fact that $F(x)<A$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Could someone verify my proof? I am not confident, because it seems fairly short. Also, is there any way to emphasize the equality can be true in limits? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are slight problems with the *statement*. (a) Do you mean "for any $c\in[a,b]$"? (b) Why should $\lim_{x\to c} F(x)$ exist? Concerning your proof, you might want to add an extra step where you choose the right epsilon to explain why $F(x)>A$ in the delta neighbourhood.

Comment: This statement doesn't make sense. First of all, you use the continuity of $F$ which is not mentioned in the statement. If $F$ is continuous, then $lim_{x\rightarrow c} F(x) = F(c) < A$ for all $c\in (a,b)$. For $c = a,b$ the limit not necessarily exists.

Comment: @Kusma You are right. (a), Yes, it should be "for any $c\in [a,b]$. (b), I left out the differentiability in the original statement. However, I cannot see why an epsilon is necessary in a proof. Could you elaborate on your comment a little bit?

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks. I meant to use the differentiability instead of continuity. Does the modified version make more sense?

Comment: Given that $F$ is differentiable on $[a,b],$ it can be easily demonstrated that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ from which it follows that $\lim_{x \to c} F(x) = F(c)$ for every $c \in [a,b].$

Comment: @Dylan_Carlo_Beck Thanks! I edited my question and added an example. Does it make more sense this time?

Comment: It is better that you rephrase the question like: if $f(x) <A$ in a certain neighborhood of $c$ (except possibly at $c$) and $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) $ exists then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) \leq A$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh What you suggested indeed is not what I meant. However, a new version is uploaded.

Comment: Given that $F(x) = \frac{1}{x},$ we have that $\lim_{x \to 0} F(x)$ does not exist: on the left-hand side, the limit is $-\infty,$ and on the right-hand side, it is $+\infty.$

Comment: You should also take care that $(a,b)$ makes sense. For instance, you could have $a = 2$ and $b = -3,$ in which case $(2,-3)$ means nothing. You need the additional assumption that $a < b.$

Comment: @Dylan_Carlo_Beck In my example, the domain of $F$ is $(0,\infty)$. I'll add $a<b$.

Comment: Correct. But the limit at zero does not exist. Given any positive real number $M,$ there exists an $x > 0$ such that $F(x) > M.$ Choose $x = \frac{1}{M + 1}.$

Comment: @Dylan_Carlo_Beck You're right.

Comment: Well, you don't need the continuity of $F$. The result you seek is true even without the continuity part. You should just mention that $F(x) <A$ in $(a, b) $. And then your question is almost same as (or a corollary of) what I suggested in previous comment. Also your proof is correct and you can see that your proof does not use continuity. A proof need not be long enough to be valid. You may just elaborate your proof by using $\epsilon =(\lim_{x\to a} F(x) - A) /2>0$ and choose your $\delta$ based on this $\epsilon $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I choose $\epsilon= lim_{x\rightarrow a} F(x)-A$ instead. It works. Thanks!

Comment: Minor edit needed. Just write that for this particular $\epsilon$ you have some $\delta>0$ such that... Note that there can't be a formula for $\delta$ like you have written.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Actually, I do think such a specific $\delta$ exist. Why do you say we cannot find a formula for $\delta$ like my written?

Comment: Finding a $\delta$ given $\epsilon$ requires the knowledge of specific properties of $F$. Here all you know about $F$ is that the limit exists (that is the existence of a $\delta$ is guaranteed) and nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with a function defined on $(a,b)$. If $c \in [a,b]$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} F(x)$ *exists*, then your argument is correct without any other assumption on $F$.

So let us see what we can say about the existence of the limit.

(1) If $c \in (a,b)$ and $F$ is continuous in $c$, then the limit exists. In this case $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} F(x) = F(c) < A$.

(2) The limit may also exist for functions which are not continuous in $c$. Take for example $F : (0,2) \to \mathbb{R}$, $F(x) = x$ for $x < 1$, $F(1) = 0$ and $F(x) = 2 - x$ for $x > 1$. Then $F(x) < 1$ for all $x$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} F(x) = 1$.

(3) For $c = a, b$ the existence of the limit does not follow from continuity or differentiability properties of $F$. Consider for example $F : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}, F(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x}$. Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} F(x)$ exists (it is $= \sin 1$), but $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} F(x)$ does not exist.